# How can I regulate pressure to a BAXI LUNA 240i boiler?

Tags: boiler

I need to increase the pressure to the boiler, how should I proceed? I checked on YouTube and found a couple of systems but they do not apply to my model (at least not at first sight).

Some pics here (click for full size):

[image]
[image]

This boiler also feeds the floor heating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's the manual in Italian and Spanish](http://www.anwo.cl/archivos/publicaciones/Manuales%20de%20Productos/Calderas/Ocean-%20Baxi/Manual%20Luna%20240_280_310.PDF)<sup>1</sup>, if you can read it.
The part about pressuring is usually covered at the beginning in maintenance but more fully explained in the installation section.

---

<sup>1</sup> Cheers for clarifying the language.

Answer (score -1):

Turn the Blue lever clockwise to add water/pressure to your central heating system!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There's not much information here; would you edit to clarify a bit? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.